# Is there a way to break up an image file into separate polygons based on colour?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, classification

I have a set of land-use maps that I created years ago in ArcMap (see image attached), I need to do more work using them but I have since lost the shapefiles. Is there any way in ArcGIS that I can break this image into polygons based on the different colours of the image? Or do I need to redraw them all by hand?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[Image classification tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/spatial-analyst/image-classification/image-classification-using-spatial-analyst.htm) can be used to reclassify your map using maximum-likelihood classification for example. You need to take training site for the area of interest. If you want the data in vector format, then you use [Rater to Polygon tool](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/conversion/raster-to-polygon.htm) from ArcToolbox to convert the re-classified image into polygon feature.

You need to have Spatial Analyst extension to use image classification tool.